# How to store a variable from a SQL Query (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, select, text, sentence

I want to Insert some data into a table and one of one I want to take it from another table.

For example :

I have 2 tables :

> Clients(Client_ID,Name,etc);
>
> Bookings(Book_ID,Client_ID(ForeignKey),Checkin,etc);

And I want to insert the Client_ID into Bookings table Where name = "john".

I think that I must store Client_ID from Clients in a variable $clientID, and when I insert into bookins will be

```
INSERT INTO bookings(Book_IT,Client_ID,Checkin) values ('1','$clientID','2015-02-20');
```

But is not working.

Can you tell how to store the Client_ID value in $clientID ?

Comment: Can you provide full code example.  That looks correct otherwise, but it would be correct if you stored the variable elsewhere in the code scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

1.select client_id where `name = "john"`

```
$sql = "SELECT Client_ID FROM clients WHERE Name = 'john'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$clientid = $rs['Client_ID'];
```

Here, `$clientid` is the `Client_ID` of `John`.

2.Insert the data in Bookings.

```
INSERT INTO bookings(Book_IT,Client_ID,Checkin) values ('1','$clientid','2015-02-20');
```

Answer (score 0):

change the query to

INSERT INTO bookings(Book_IT,Client_ID,Checkin) values ('1',$clientID,'2015-02-20');

and it will work

Comment: try it.. the bracket around $clientID was causing the issue.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was under the impression that the query was enveloped by `'`. My bad! :)

Comment: But how I store the Client_ID value from clients table ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a select query first which selects  Client_ID Where name = "john" from your 'Clients' table and store the result in a array .. after that just loop the array and insert each client it by using your above insert statement ..